# Qt / Send data from mainwindow to dialog or grab a data from mainwindow?

Tags: c++, qt

There are two files:
 `mainwindow.cpp` and `editorplain.cpp`

`editorplain.cpp` is dialog as widget.

Problem: Send text data to label on another dialog.

`mainwidnow.cpp`

Action on triggered from menu call a new dialog:
`er` will return string from mainwindow.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionRoot_files_triggered()
{
    QString er = ui->selected_filename->text();

    Editorplain editorplainwidget;
    // HERE IS WHAT I WANT SEND A DATA TO ANOTHER DIALOG `editorplain`
    editorplainwidget.exec();
}
```

When opening dialog I want a grab data from string `er`:

```
Editorplain::setData(myType myData)
{
    ui->label_2->setText(myData.textForEdit);
}
```

Let's explain my problem. On `mywindow` I have a string `er` which returns some string as result. This `er` should send on dialog `editorplain` and set as label for example: `ui->label->setText(er)`. Label is QLabel made on `QDialog`.

`Mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
     public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
     private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_triggered();

    void on_actionExit_triggered();

    void on_actionRoot_files_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`editorplain.cpp` file:

```
#include "editorplain.h"
#include "ui_editorplain.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Editorplain::Editorplain(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Editorplain)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // SHOULD PASS ON THIS CONTRUCTOR?

}

Editorplain::~Editorplain()
{
    delete ui;
}

Editorplain::setData(myType myData)
{
    ui->label_2->setText(myData.textForEdit);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its a custom QDialog just make the function `setData()` public . That way you can call the function from MainWindow passing your string before showing the dialog. You do not then need to pass anything through the constructor.

Something like in `editorplain.h`

```
public:
void setData(const QString &labelText);
```

and `editorplain.cpp`

```
void Editorplain::setData(const QString &labelText) {
  ui->label_2->setText(labelText);
}
```

Now in `mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::on_actionRoot_files_triggered()
{
    QString er = ui->selected_filename->text();

    Editorplain editorplainwidget;
    editorplainwidget.setData(er);
    editorplainwidget.exec();
}
```

Comment: TRUE! EXACTLY what I need! But, small mistakes, repaired: `void EditorPlain::setData(const QString &labelText) {` to `void Editorplain::setData(const QString &labelText) {`

Comment: :) updated the class name in the answer. You can up-vote and accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass that string to `Editorplain` constructor, if that isn't a problem.

Comment: Pass a string like `Eeditorplain::something()` in Sources `editorplain.cpp`  ?